# Invalid syntax error: Building decision tree with Python and Spark, Churn prediction

Tags: python, apache-spark, syntax-error, decision-tree

As title suggests: I am working on a decision tree model for churn prediction. I am a total beginner of data science, python and spark.

Combined with all the examples from the lectures and online documentations, I managed to come up with a Decision tree model. The only issue is, the error calculation funkction is giving me a syntax error.

Basically, the data I use for the model looks like this:

```
[LabeledPoint(0.0, [1031.0,947.0,0.333333333333,10.9933333333,10.3,12.0,1.33333333333,10.0133333333,83.6666666667,5.86,55.69,0.596666666667,10.3333333333,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.666666666667,23.3333333333,2.88333333333,25.0,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.666666666667,135.333333333,4.44,0.06,0.333333333333,16.3333333333,0.98,0.333333333333,57.6666666667,3.46,0.333333333333,0.0,0.0,0.333333333333,14.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,5.66666666667,22.0166666667,130.48,0.0,65.3333333333,0.0,287.333333333,34.0,113.666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [4231.0,951.0,1.33333333333,27.5466666667,6.45,22.0,1.0,12.0133333333,46.3333333333,6.45,47.15,1.32333333333,8.81,1.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.33333333333,31.6666666667,6.4,42.6566666667,1.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.33333333333,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,57.0,0.0,0.0,57.0,0.0,0.0,57.0,0.0,0.0,57.0,10.6666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,4.0,32.0266666667,156.966666667,0.0,145.43,0.0,1.66666666667,0.0,0.333333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [5231.0,523.0,0.666666666667,14.62,1.1,1307.0,0.0,0.0,14.3333333333,1.1,7.57333333333,0.726666666667,4.84,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.666666666667,8.33333333333,0.323333333333,2.15666666667,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,8.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,0.0,0.0,47.33,0.0,10.3566666667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [6031.0,741.0,7.0,5.38666666667,2.13,58.0,0.333333333333,4.0,21.3333333333,1.35333333333,11.2966666667,0.48,3.2,8.33333333333,0.666666666667,0.0,0.0,8.33333333333,11.3333333333,0.453333333333,3.03,8.33333333333,1.0,0.0133333333333,0.166666666667,8.33333333333,2.33333333333,0.776666666667,0.363333333333,23.0,1.33333333333,0.08,23.0,0.0,0.0,23.0,0.333333333333,0.03,23.0,9.33333333333,0.666666666667,1.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,1.33333333333,16.0,61.25,3.31666666667,10.94,3.65,11.3333333333,7.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0]),
LabeledPoint(0.0, [8831.0,840.0,5.33333333333,2.21,2.76,35.6666666667,0.666666666667,4.0,66.3333333333,2.76,17.7466666667,0.283333333333,1.20666666667,5.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.33333333333,42.6666666667,2.43333333333,16.2166666667,5.33333333333,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.33333333333,1.0,0.0,0.0,23.0,0.0,0.0,23.0,0.666666666667,0.0,23.0,0.0,0.0,23.0,6.33333333333,0.0,1.33333333333,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1307.0,1.66666666667,10.0,62.6333333333,0.0,56.7833333333,0.0,4.33333333333,0.666666666667,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0])]
```

And then I use the code provided in Spark documentation for decision trees:

```
# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a DecisionTree model.
#  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                 impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)

# Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
predictions = model.predict(testData.map(lambda x: x.features))
labelsAndPredictions = testData.map(lambda lp: lp.label).zip(predictions)
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(testData.count())
print('Test Error = ' + str(testErr))
print('Learned classification tree model:')
print(model.toDebugString())
```

And

```
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(testData.count())
```

is giving me the error of:

```
  File "<ipython-input-70-e37b435ea51d>", line 1
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(testData.count())
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In case someone would like to see the whole code, I put it [here in my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwckvgc9sf1azc4/aisvais%2Bkmeans-Copy3%20%281%29.html?dl=0)

I have no idea, why it gives me this error. Seems like this line is working fine for other people. So I am afraid it could be related to steps before the model creation..

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't get a syntax error with `labelsAndPredictions = ...; testErr = ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lambda (v, p)` is only valid Python syntax for Python 2.7 and below. You're probably using Python 3, where [tuple parameter packing is no longer allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

I believe the 3.X-compatible version would look like:

```
testErr = labelsAndPredictions.filter(lambda seq: seq[0] != seq[1]).count() / float(testData.count())
```

Comment: Yes, that works, I am amazed that it wasn't related to my tricks with data.. Thank you and happy holidays! :)

Answer (score 2):

`lambda` expressions don't need parenthesis when having multiple arguments, so
`lambda (v, p):` should be `lambda v, p:`

`lambda (x,y):` is a valid syntax only in Python 2. In Python 3 it's a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: `a = lambda (x,v): x*v
print a((2,2))` Returns 4

Comment: But anyways you have clarified your point.  `when having multiple arguments`

Comment: @MYGz Only in Python 2. In Python 3 it's a SyntaxError.

Comment: Oh. I'm on python2.7